# How to get path to a template in iron router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

How can I get the path to a template in new version of iron-router for Meteor 1.0?

Before I could do this to get the current relative path:

```
Router.current().path
```

Now, as of meteor 1.0 it seems the path attribute has been removed.

How can I get the relative path to a template in iron-router?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Router.current().path
```

This has been moved to `Router.current().location.get().path`

See the `iron:location` package for more info on the location object.

https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-location

(this is added automatically by `iron:router`).

Comment: Cool. I though it must have been moved. I think you forgot a get() there though.

Comment: `Router.current().location.get().path` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will be helpful for you: `Router.current().originalUrl` or `Router.current().url`

Comment: Well, sort of, but this is only the full url and it doesn't have the possibility to set variables in the path.

Comment: well. Its good enough. The current url is fine and the `Router.routes['page'].path({var: 1})` seems to be working actually. My bad. Thanks!